# Many to many relationship and where in Laravel 4

Tags: php, many-to-many, where-clause, laravel, laravel-4

In Laravel 4, when working with many-to-many relationships, I would like to do the following:

```
/* get all skills for one specific topic */
Route::get( '/api/topics/{topicSlug}/skills', function( $topicSlug )
{
    $skills = Skill::where( 'topic.slug', '=', $topicSlug )->get();
}
```

Now the problem is that `topic.slug` obviously isn't a column in the `skills` table. Instead, `slug` is a column in the `topics` table, which is related to the `skills` table via a pivot table called `skills_topics` (which includes `skill_id` and `topic_id`).

I've tried a number of variations, but I just can't get the query right. **How does the query have to look like, if I want to get all skills for one particular topic?**

---

The models are:

```
class Skill extends Eloquent {
    public function topics()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany( 'Topic' ); 
    }
}
```

and

```
class Topic extends Eloquent {
    public function skills()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany( 'Skill' );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you should actually get the topic with the related skills if I understood correctly. Something like this:

```
$topic = Topic::with('skills')->where('slug', $topicSlug)->first();
```

And the access the skills through:

```
foreach ($topic->skills as $skill) {  }
```

Comment: You need to change `topic.slug` to just `slug`. Now to get a json-response that includes all skills which belongs to $topic, I just need to do `return $topic->skills;`. I was approaching it totally the wrong way around. Thanks so much, that really helped :)

Comment: Yep, I copy/pasted your part ;)